# Biometric authentication process

Tags: fingerprint, variance

I am working on the fingerprint image taken from a cmos camera. There is a grey opaque circle at the center of the image frame and dark grey boundary towards the edges. Once I scan the fingerprint on the sensor, the contrast of the ridges are almost equal (with very less variation) to the background image. I am trying to get a clear boundary of the ridges and valleys, so that I can calculate minutiae (I am working on minutiae method for fingerprint recognition).

Initially, I am looking to detect the presence of the finger. I am trying to use the variance method for this. But, since the contrast difference of fore ground and background image is very low, I am getting low difference in calculating the variance. The code for calculating the variance is given below :

**

```
int get_variance(unsigned char *input, int size)
{
    int i,mean = get_mean(input,size);
    int temp = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        temp += (input[i]-mean) * (input[i]-mean);
    }
    return (temp/size);
}
int get_mean(unsigned char *input, int size)
{
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        sum += input[i];
    }
    return (sum/size);
}
```

**
The image resolution is 320x240.

The variance for the background is around 1200 and the variance for the background with fingerprint is around 950. This is the maximum variance I get on both images. And even at times, the background alone at low lighting conditions gives 950.

What I can do to improve the finger detection process ? Will it be helpful if I convert the image to frequency domain ? Or can I use fingerprint segmentation for detecting the presence of finger print ?